# Adding zeroes in CAT function

Tags: sas

I'm using the CAT-Function to generate variable names:

```
variable=CAT(ID,ID2,Number)
```

The variable "number" is a number from the set {1,5,52,142,299}. As I want to have the same structure for all generated variables, I would like to add zeroes in front of the numbers, i.e. as {001,005,052,142,299}. How can I achieve that inside the CAT-function?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z` format adds leading zeros to a specified number of digits, in your case it would be `z3.`.  Use the `put` function to convert it to a character string in the required format (`cat` returns a character string by default, so would have to convert the number anyhow).  You may want to consider `cats` as an alternative, which will strip any leading or trailing blanks.

`variable=CAT(ID,ID2,put(Number,z3.))`